# SQLServer Agent jobs and shutting down PC

Tags: sql-server

Using SQLServer 2008.

Just curious as to what happens when an administrator shuts down a server machine when an SQL Server Agent job happens to be running. In our case, the jobs could take several minutes to run (i.e. transaction log shipping COPY and RESTORE jobs).

What will happen to the running jobs - will they be allowed to complete before the machine is shutdown, or is there some upper waiting period before the jobs are killed etc (if killed, what determines the waiting period etc).

Is it safer to stop the jobs manually before shutting down the machine ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expect the running jobs to stop when the SQL Agent service stops. I use log shipping and routinely shut down my LSCopy & LSRetore jobs just so I know the state of log shipping prior to server shutdown.